# Boyd & Vandenberghe, example 3.14 — How is convexity established?

Tags: convex-analysis

From Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/), the second last example of 3.14 is as follows.

---

[image]

---

I am not able to follow why $h(z)$ would be convex. We can write it as $h(z) = (g(z))^{\frac1p}$, where

$$g(z) = \sum_{i=1}^k \max \{z_i, 0\}^p $$

I am able to follow why $g(z)$ is convex, but not able to follow why $h(z)$ would be too. I think trying to prove convexity from $g(z)$ is not a good idea as we are not considering the power of $p$ used in $g$.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790)

Comment: $x\mapsto x^{1/p}$ is convex non-decreasing if $p\geq 1$. It is easy to see that if $\varphi$ is convex non-decreasing, and $\psi$ is convex, then $\varphi \circ \psi$ is convex

Comment: @Andrew say p = 2, then x^0.5 or root(x) is concave, non-decreasing not convex non-decreasing.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't ever read Boyd's book, but I hope the following [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) is helpful: For any $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb R$ and $p\geqslant 1$, we have
$$
\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i+b_i|^p\Big)^{1/p}\leqslant\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|^p\Big)^{1/p}+\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n|b_i|^p\Big)^{1/p}.
$$
The convexity of $h$ follows, as we show below.

---

We write vectors as $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \dots x_n)$.
For each $i \in [n]$, define the function $g_i : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ as
$$
g_i(\mathbf{x}) = \max(x_i, 0 )
\enspace,
$$
which is convex and non-negative. We will now show that

$$
h(\mathbf{x}) = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n g_i(\mathbf{x})^p \right)^{1/p}
$$

is convex, using Minkowski's inequality.

Let $0\leqslant \lambda \leqslant1$ and let $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Observe that
$$
\begin{aligned}
h \big( \lambda \mathbf{x} + (1-\lambda) \mathbf{y} \big)
&= \Big(\sum_{i=1}^k g_i(\lambda \mathbf{x} +(1-\lambda) \mathbf{y} )^p\Big)^{1/p} \\
&\leqslant \Big(\sum_{i=1}^k \big(\lambda g_i(\mathbf{x})+(1-\lambda)g_i(\mathbf{y}) \big)^p\Big)^{1/p} \\
&\leqslant\Big(\sum_{i=1}^k(\lambda g_i(\mathbf{x})^p \Big)^{1/p}+\Big(\sum_{i=1}^k((1-\lambda)g_i(\mathbf{y}))^p\Big)^{1/p} \\
&=\lambda \Big(\sum_{i=1}^k g_i(\mathbf{x})^p\Big)^{1/p}+(1-\lambda) \Big(\sum_{i=1}^k g_i(\mathbf{y})^p\Big)^{1/p} \\
&= \lambda h(\mathbf{x}) + (1-\lambda) h(\mathbf{y})
\enspace,
\end{aligned}
$$
where the first inequality follows from convexity of each $g_i$ and the second inequality is Minkowski's inequality, taking $a_i = \lambda g_i(\mathbf{x})$ and $b_i = (1-\lambda) g_i(\mathbf{y})$.

Comment: I am not able to follow...

Comment: could you describe more which parts are difficult to follow? I've added an edit, though it's still awaiting approval.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. The function $f(t) = \| t \|_p = (\sum_{i=1}^k t_i^p)^{1/p}$ is convex since it's a norm for $p \geq 1$, and all norms are convex. Moreover, $f(z)$ is increasing in every component $t_i$ when $t \geq 0$.

The functions $\phi_i(z) = \max \{ z_i, 0\}$ are also convex as a maximum of two convex functions, and their range is non-negative.

Thus,
$$
h(z) = \left( \sum_{i=1}^k \max\{ z_i, 0 \}^p \right)^{1/p} = f(\phi_1(z), \dots, \phi_k(z))
$$
is convex as a composition of a convex non-decreasing function onto convex functions.